# strange behavior of the floating html-element

Tags: html, css, css-float, media-queries

I got a trouble with floating element in my project, and after code diagnostic it reduced to this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7re8j448/1/

```css
#one, #two {
    display:inline-block;
    background: green;
}
#two {
    float:left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #one, #two {
        display: block;
        background: red;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
    <span id="one">One</span>
    <span id="two">Two</span>
</div>
```

The trouble show itself, if you will resize the result part less than 320px (bg should become red), and then raise it back to the green bg.

The float element "two", which stay in the left of "one"-element at start, after resize going under "one". I guess that happens because I make it block at <320px size, and browser didn't understand, that after resize it shoud came back in string first, and float only after that.

How can I fix it?

Thanks for your help, and I'm sorry about my english.

UPD: I don't need both of elements float. Only the "two".

UPD2: I'm sorry of my bad explain. Let's clear some points.
In the real case I have more than 2 elements, which are comlicated change their positions depend on screen width. The order of elements is important, because elements of the end are become block and hide itself in revealing mobile menu.

Comment: What does "fixing it" entail exactly? Do you want two to come after one in green, or two to not go under one in red?

Comment: The problem is, you unset the float for one direction but don't set it to float in the other. You unset the float for a max-width but don't have anything for resetting it back.

Comment: I want them to return in TwoOne position

Comment: Not sure if it helps but I made a fiddle which logs the propeties to the console: https://jsfiddle.net/1v7dfxpc/ might maybe help with debugging, but didn't help me very much as the propeties are the same on a resize as they are when initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing the `display` property of `#one` just set the width to be 100%.

```css
#one,
#two {
  background: green;
}
#one {
  display: initial;
  display: inline-block;
}
#two {
  float: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  #one,
  #two {
    background: red;
  }
  #one {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #two {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div"> <span id="one">One</span>
  <span id="two">Two</span>

</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5eybdp47/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want "two" always come first for small devices also then you can change place of span two. Then it will work

```
<div id="div">
    <span id="two">Two</span>
    <span id="one">One</span>
</div>

#one, #two {
    display:inline-block;
    background: green;
}
#two {
    float:left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
     #one,#two{
        display: block;
        background: red;
        float: none;

    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, but there are more complicated changes, then it shown in the fiddle. I want to understand, why the browser (I use chrome) do what it do. Why view of the page depends, have I resized page or not.

Comment: I did not got what you are talking about but I checked with this html and this its working..                                                                                                                                                 #one, #two {
    display:inline-block;
    background: green;
}
#two {
    float:left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
     #one,#two{
        display: block;
        background: red;
        float: none;
        
    }
}                    <div id="div">
    <span id="two">Two</span>
    <span id="one">One</span>
    
</div>

Comment: I've updated the question. I can't change the order of elements in html. 
I'm confused of situation. Imagine you have an iPhone 4 (320px*480px). You load the page in landscape orientation, switch to portrait, then switch back and now have broken page. With the same css rules and the same html-markup.

Answer (score -1):

you are facing the problem because you have mentioned the float in only #two not in #one , what that results in to is parent div do not consider floated element #two and keeps it out that is why it shows on next line 
to fix this issue i have added float in both #two and # one and have also added float in parent div so that it will consider the both floated child inside

```css
#one, #two {
    display:inline-block;
    background: green;
    float:left;
}
#div{float:left;width:100%;}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #one, #two {
        display: block;
        background: red;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
    <span id="one">One</span>
    <span id="two">Two</span>
</div>
```